# Steam API fetching empty response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, fetch-api, steam

I am using steam API for one of my projects, but the response from API is null/empty. It is working fine with Postman but in browser it is not.

API: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/

```js
let apiInfo = async function() {
        fetch(`http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/`, {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors'
        })
        .then(response => { console.log(response); return response.text()})
        .then((dataFromServer) => {
            console.log(dataFromServer);
        })
        .catch(error => window.alert(error));
    }
```

And my response looks like this:

```js
Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: null
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
[[Prototype]]: Response
```

**The API fetches information about ID's associated with the games**.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or how can I make it work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [no-cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode): *Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET or POST, and the headers from being anything other than simple headers. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not add or override any headers except for those that are simple headers. In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting Response* - in other words, don't use `no-cors` if you want to access the response - please note: that API doesn't allow CORS access